# Problem with SOAP request

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

I'm getting the error: "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction:"

Does it necessarily say the problem is with my soap action? or can it also be in my soap message?

I want to debug this issue but don't know where to start... =\

10x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check a couple of things:

1. Did the namespace for the web service change? - This can generate the error because the deserialization of the xml being posted to the service fails due to a mismatch in the namespaces of the posted xml and the namespace the service expects.
2. Did the method being requested get removed from the web service? - Not likely but a missing method might cause the same problem.  More likely #1.

Any of these will be fixed by updating your application's reference to the wsdl of the web service.

Comment: well, I don't use the wsdl file - it is hidden. I know the available methods by asking my webService developer

Comment: Compare the xml namespace of the web service reference generated and what the actual web service namespace is.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand you mate. What are these 2 values?

Comment: When you add a reference to a web service in .NET it generates a Reference.vb file.  This is the proxy class that defines how your code talks to the web service.  In there you will see a namespace defined.  You need to compare that value with what the namespace is of the actual service the dev you are working with has used for the web service.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, there is a SOAPAction header in your HTTP request and the server isn't recognizing the value.  Can you examine or modify the headers being sent in the request?